# PHP parse content

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have this content in a variable in PHP.
How do I make a foreach where I have the field name in one variable and the value in another?

```
<Transaction id="1">
<Table name="if_802_11_stats">
<Body status="0" statusdescription="" startrecord="1" endrecord="242"     totalrecords="242">
<Entry status="0">
<Field name="IfIndex">1</Field>
<Field name="NodeType">ap</Field>
</Entry>
<Entry status="0">
<Field name="IfIndex">2</Field>
<Field name="NodeType">ap</Field>
</Entry>
</Body>
</Table>
</Transaction>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Comment: How do I then foreach when i have the two variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561657/loop-through-an-xml-object-with-simplexml