# How can I format XML?

Tags: php, html, xml

I have worked out how to cURL the JSS Casper API in PHP, and receive a response in XML. In the browser, it just formats everything without any whitespace on one line. Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<accounts>
  <users>
    <user>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>administrator</name>
    </user>
  </users>
  <groups>
    <group>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Example Group</name>
      <site>
        <id>-1</id>
        <name>None</name>
      </site>
    </group>
  </groups>
</accounts>
```

How can I format this into a HTML table or something prettier? Is there a simple way of converting it?

Here is the code I tried:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.jamfcloud.com/JSSResource/accounts");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $arr = simplexml_load_string_($curl);
    $xml = $arr->member;
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($xml as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->user ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->id ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->name ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Here's [an example](https://gist.github.com/betweenbrain/5405671) you could try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) wrong:

```
$arr = simplexml_load_string_($curl);
```

should actually be:

```
$arr = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Remove

```
$xml = $arr->member;
```

since you can just replace the `foreach` loop like:

```
<?php foreach($arr->users->user as $row) { ?>
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561750/2006429).