# How to loop through multiple identical XML Tags?

Tags: php, xml

So I have a XML I am parsing and loading data into DB. However, my current code is listing only 1 out 3 names.

Taking the below example, my code is only loading Class name Alpha1. Is there a way where I can loop through all "Code" tags?

```
<ClassList>
    <Class>
        <Code>Alpa1</Code>
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <Code>Bravo1</Code>
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <Code>Charlie1</Code>
    </Class>        
</ClassList>
```

My PHP Code is the below:

```
$ClassCode  = $xmlfiles->ClassList->Class->Code;
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an XML object with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561657/loop-through-an-xml-object-with-simplexml)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably with two loops, see https://eval.in/865302

```
foreach ($sxml->Class as $class) {
  foreach ($class->Code as $code) {
    echo (string) $code, PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

The reason your code isn't working is that the line

```
$xmlfiles->ClassList->Class->Code;
```

is short-hand for `$xmlfiles->ClassList[0]->Class[0]->Code`. You can loop over this, but you'll only be operating within the first `<Class>` tag. Also note that the SimpleXML object will be "anchored" to the root `<ClassList>` tag automatically, so you don't need to include that.

Another option would be to use `XPath`, which allows you to specify an arbitrary selector:

```
foreach ($sxml->xpath('Class/Code') as $code) {
  echo (string) $code, PHP_EOL;
}
```