# How do I loop through a cURL simpleXML object?

Tags: php, curl, simplexml

I have retrieved the xml file successfully and printed it out as an array but what I want to do is loop through the file and perform some operations on each record.
I tried a foreach loop with ->children but I just can;t seem to print anything

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, Array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => 'http://www.test.co.uk/test.xml',
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'spider',
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => 'UTF-8'
));
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
//die('<pre>' . print_r($xml, TRUE) . '</pre>');
echo $xml->row[0]['user'];
die();
```

Data looks like this in the array:

```
<pre>SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [row] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [user] => aaa
                    [enabled] => 1
                    [email_address] => aaa@gmail.com
                    [OrderDate] => 2018-08-01 10:25:04
                    [products_id] => 381
                    [NewOrder] => 0
                    [ResendKeys] => 0
                    [LastUpdate] => 2018-12-19 02:36:26
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [user] => bbb
                    [enabled] => 1
                    [email_address] => bbb@gmail.com
                    [OrderDate] => 2018-12-19 02:50:27
                    [products_id] => 380
                    [NewOrder] => 0
                    [ResendKeys] => 1
                    [LastUpdate] => 2018-12-19 02:50:27
                )
```

Comment: `foreach ($xml->row as $row)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an XML object with SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561657/loop-through-an-xml-object-with-simplexml)

Comment: Firstly, the result is not an array, it's an object. Secondly, you haven't actually shown us the loop you tried, so it's impossible for us to tell you why it didn't work.