# append xml nodes inside another node in php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I want to insert different nodes inside the  node. but i dont know how to do it dynamically

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'  encoding='UTF-8'?>
<article artId="4686453" artName="UHOPI20190218-012A" Author="" Comment="" PubDate="2019-02-18" Section="country">
 <head>
    <headline>this is the title </headline>
    <summary>
        autor name @twitter
    </summary>
  </head>
 <body>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer venenatis eleifend dui, at egestas sapien lobortis viverra.
<!-- insert pullquotes here -->
  </body>
<pullquote title="" catsList="" summary="" notes="" sectionColor="" sectionHead="">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    <summary xml:space="preserve">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </summary>
  </pullquote>
<pullquote title="" catsList="" summary="" notes="" sectionColor="" sectionHead="">
    <headline xml:space="preserve">Some text</headline>
    <summary xml:space="preserve">Some text</summary>
    <summary xml:space="preserve">Some text</summary>
</pullquote>
</article>
```

I try this...but it doesnt work

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("files/test2.xml");
$body = $xml->body;
$pull1 = $xml->pullquote[0];
$body->addChild($pull1);
```

I want to insert every  node inside the  node 
how can i do this?

Comment: Loop over them …? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19561750/10283047

Comment: yes but how can i put inside the body

Comment: By using the `addChild` method on the body node - you’ll just have to specify node name and node value of the node you want to add separately. (Plus you’ll have to remove the existing ones yourself afterwards then though.) If you want a bit more finesse than that, then you need to switch to a library that is a bit more sophisticated, such as DomDocument - that has a proper appendChild DOM method, that allows you to “move” an existing element to a different position in the DOM tree.

Comment: thanks! do you have an example please.. Im lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
if($xmlData->body){
    $xmlIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xmlData->body->asXML());
    $xmlIterator->rewind();
    $txtBody = "";

    for($i=0; $i < ($xmlIterator->count()); $i++){
            $txtBody .= (trim($xmlIterator->current()) <> '') ? "<p>".trim($xmlIterator->current())."</p>" : "";
                            $xmlIterator->next();
                        }
                        #INSERT PULLQUOTE
                        foreach($xmlData->pullquote as $pull){
                            $txtBody .= $pull;

                            foreach ($pull->children() as $child){
                                $txtBody .= $child;
                            }

                        }

                        $data = $txtBody;
}
```